# Can cache / persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK lose data?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

My Spark RDD is cached with `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK` setting.
Event if it would be saved on memory or disk, is there any way that the RDD recompute to re-create this RDD?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What are you referring to with "is there any way that the RDD recompute to re-create this RDD?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Dataframe.cache() behavior for changing source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855849/spark-dataframe-cache-behavior-for-changing-source)